# "The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time"

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, permissions, authorization, facebook-oauth

I am using the iOS Built in frameworks to connect. After asking for `"publish_stream"` permissions, FB returns an error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time." UserInfo=0x145ad6a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time.}
```

What is going on here? Showing two user permission popups is a less than ideal user experience.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The very first time, you must ask for read permissions. You cannot auth the user initially with any type of publish/write permissions. What you should do after that is, where it makes sense in your app, ask for publish_stream permission. Definitely do not do the initial permission and then immediately ask for the publish_stream permission.

See this note in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/, section "Asking for Read & Write Permissions Separately". Even though this applies to the Facebook SDK for iOS it is an extension of the same requirement in the built-in framework.

Comment: I'm asking for @"user_about_me" and still got this error. What's wrong ??

Comment: Are you asking for only user_about_me when you get this error? Also if you can provide the code you're using that will help.

Comment: thanks the problem is already fixed. There were some lags on Facebook

Comment: This is really poor design. My app just needs to publish to the user's news feed without reading anything. The docs say `It is important that you do not simply attempt to call the two individual methods back-to-back to replace either of the deprecated functions.` How am I supposed to ask for read permissions first without asking for them back-to-back other than to pop up a dialog at some random time?

Comment: The Share Dialog released with 3.5 (in limited beta right now), should help you out Kevin.

Comment: I found replacing the previous permission with @"basic_info" ([FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"]) fixed it for me. I also found that the order mattered and that @[@"public_profile", @"basic_info"] didn't work even though it contained the basic info call

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add that there is an additional caveat in the Facebook docs:

```
// if a user has *never* logged into your app, you MUST include one of
// "email", "user_location", or "user_birthday".  Other read 
// permissions can also be included here.
```

Failure to do this leads to the same error.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest SDK (v3.5) you also need to pass @"basic_info" in the permissions array. It used to be implicit, but not anymore. If you don't, you'll get the "The app must ask for a basic read permission at install time" message

```
  [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"basic_info"]
                                 allowLoginUI:YES
                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                            }];
```

From the method docs:

> readPermissions - An array of strings representing the read
>   permissions to request during the authentication flow. The basic_info
>   permission must be explicitly requested at first login, and is no
>   longer inferred, (subject to an active migration.) It is not allowed
>   to pass publish permissions to this method.